# Store result of Jinja filter

Tags: set, jinja2

The basics of what I am trying to do is to use the 'random' filter to choose a random item from my list but then I want to use that randomly chosen item in multiple locations.

How do I set the result of a filter to a variable that I can use in multiple locations.

If I call the 'random' filter multiple times there is little chance they will be the same.

Essentially what I want to do:

```
{% set image = {{ images | random }} %}
```

obviously this doesnt work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the filter without `{{` `}}` delimiters.

```
{% set image = images|random %}
```

Jinja stores *[globals](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/?highlight=block#jinja2.Environment.globals)* and *[filters](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/?highlight=block#jinja2.Environment.filters)* in two different namespaces (dictionaries), which prevents them from being used interchangeably.

Comment: If somebody has multiple parameters, this answer in combination with this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48532564/7335848 can help.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up here because I thought the `set` command wouldn't work, until I finally understood that the `set` command is inside a `for` loop in a different scope and the value is no longer available outside the loop.

My first approach was as follows - but it didn't work:

```
{% set search_replace = {'Hello': 'Welcome', 'red': 'blue'} %}
{% set my_string = 'Hello World! I have a red car.' %}
{% for find, replace in search_replace.items() %}
{% set my_string = my_string | replace(find, replace) %}
{% endfor %}
{{ my_string }}
```

The result always corresponded to the input:

> Hello World! I have a red car.

However, it is not impossible to store a value inside a loop so that it is still available outside the loop.

#### set inside a loop, use value outside the loop

Since Jinja 2.10 there is a solution for this using [`namespace` functionality](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-globals.namespace).

Example:

```
{% set search_replace = {'Hello': 'Welcome', 'red': 'blue'} %}
{% set my_string = 'Hello World! I have a red car.' %}
{% set ns = namespace(my_string=my_string) %}
{% for find, replace in search_replace.items() %}
{% set ns.my_string = ns.my_string | replace(find, replace) %}
{% endfor %}
{{ ns.my_string }}
```

Now the result is as expected:

> Welcome World! I have a blue car.

#### Explanation

- The variable `my_string` can be accessed within the loop, but it cannot be changed using `{% set %}`.
- Therefore, a new variable `ns` is created with the function `namespace`. Using `my_string=my_string`, the element `my_string` is defined for `ns` and the variable `my_string` is assigned to it as the initial value.
- Within the loop, you do not work with `my_string`, but with `ns.my_string`.
- `ns.my_string` can easily be redefined using `{% set %}`, just as `ns.my_string` can simply be read.
- If you then access the namespace variable `ns` outside the loop using `ns.my_string`, the value is still available.
- The whole thing works because a namespace is defined for `ns`, which is effectively a separate scope that is addressed via the namespace variable `ns`.

Answer (score -1):

It's not working on loop, I had used this code:

```
{% set result = result | replace('x','y') %}
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77595290)