# app_template_filter with multiple arguments

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

How can I pass two arguments to `app_template_filter` [(doc)](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/api/#flask.Blueprint.app_template_filter)? This works well if I use only one argument. But in this case, I need two.

```
@mod.app_template_filter('posts_page')
def posts(post_id, company_id):
    pass
```

---

```
{{ post.id, post.company.id | posts_page }}
```

**Error:**

```
TypeError: posts_page() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [Jinja docs](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#filters),

> Variables can be modified by filters. Filters are separated from the variable by a pipe symbol (|) and may have optional arguments in parentheses. Multiple filters can be chained. The output of one filter is applied to the next.

Filters are designed to *modify* one variable at a time. You're looking for a [`context processor`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templating/#context-processors):

> Variables are not limited to values; a context processor can also make functions available to templates (since Python allows passing around functions)

For example,

```
@app.context_processor
def add():
    def _add(int1, int2):
        return int(int1) + int(int2)
    return dict(add=_add)
```

can be used in the template as

```
{{ add(a, b) }}
```

You can adopt this as your `posts_page` method:

```
@app.context_processor
def posts_page():
    def _posts_page(post_id, company_id):
        # ...
        return value
    return dict(posts_page=_posts_page)
```

Answer (score 29):

While you may use a context processor, it may not always be what you want.

The docs snippet in the accepted answer says:

> [Filters] may have optional arguments in parentheses.

So, looking at the asker's template filter:

```
@mod.app_template_filter('posts_page')
def posts(post_id, company_id):
    pass
```

The following is valid in the template:

```
{{ post.id|posts_page(post.company_id) }}
```

Comment: If they had simply put this single line example snippet in the docs it would clear up all the confusion and need to ask questions. Anyways, thanks for the answer. This should really be the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it, but the purists might not like it, it might not be "pythonistic" given the "modify one variable" thing. However, I realize that modifying one variable might require input from several values.

Template:

```
{% set args = { 'post_id': post.id, 'company_id': post.company.id } %}
...
{{ args | posts_page }}
```

Server:

```
@mod.app_template_filter('posts_page')
def posts(args):
    post_id    = args['post_id']
    company_id = args['company_id']
```